# How to get a Webworker really responsive and why setTimeout() not working

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I am studying Javascript Web Workers. To do so, I created the page and script below:

worker-test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web Worker Test</title>
    <script src="worker-test.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<form>
    <table width="50%">
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td width="25%">
                <label >Step Time</label>
                <select id="stepTime" onchange="changeStepTime();">
                    <option>500</option>
                    <option>1000</option>
                    <option>2000</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td width="25%">
                <button id="btnStart" onclick="return buttonAction('START');">Start</start>
            </td>
            <td width="25%">
                <button id="btnStop" onclick="return buttonAction('STOP');">Stop</start>
            </td>
            <td width="25%">
                <button id="btnClean" onclick="return clean();">Clean</start>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <textarea id="log" rows="15" style="width: 100%; font-size: xx-large;"  readonly="readonly"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

worker-test.js

```
function id(strId) {
    return document.getElementById(strId);
}

worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.onmessage =  function(e) {
    switch(e.data.msg) {
        case "STARTED":
            console.info(e.data);
            id("btnStart").disabled = true;
            id("btnStop").disabled = false;
            break;
        case "STOPPED":
            console.info(e.data);
            id("btnStart").disabled = false;
            id("btnStop").disabled = true;
            break;
        case "TIME":
            id("log").value += e.data.time + '\n';
            break
        default:
            // ...
    }
};

function buttonAction(action) {
    worker.postMessage({msg: action}); 
    return false;
}

function changeStepTime() {
    worker.postMessage({msg: "STEPTIME", stepTime: id("stepTime").value});
}

function clean() {
    id('log').value = ''; 
    return false;
}

function init() {
    id("btnStop").disabled = true;
    changeStepTime();
}
```

worker.js

```
var running = false;
var stepTime = 0;

// Replacement of setTimeout().
function pause() {
    var t0 = Date.now();
    while((Date.now() - t0) < stepTime) {
        (function() {}) ();
    }
}

function run() {
    while(running) {
        postMessage({msg: "TIME", time: new Date().toISOString()});
        // pause();
        setTimeout(function() {console.debug("PAUSE!!!")}, stepTime);
    }
}

addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    switch(e.data.msg) {
        case "START":
            running = true;
            console.debug("[WORKER] STARTING. running = " + running);
            run();
            postMessage({msg: "STARTED"});
            break;
        case "STOP":
            running = false;
            console.debug("[WORKER] STOPPING. running = " + running);
            postMessage({msg: "STOPPED"});
            break;
        case "STEPTIME":
            stepTime = parseInt(e.data.stepTime);
            console.debug("[WORKER] STEP TIME = " + stepTime);
            postMessage({msg: "STEP TIME CHANGED"});
            break;
        default:
            console.warn("[WORKER] " + e.data);
    }
});
```

How the page is supposed to do: When I click in *Start* Button, it sends a message to worker which call run function. In this function there is a while loop. There, first is sent a message to UI thread with the current time in the to be shown in the `<TEXTAREA>`. Next, the `setTimeout()` is called to pause in the time setted by `stepTime` `<SELECT>` element. Also, when the loop starts, the *Start* button must be disabled and the *Stop* one enabled. When the *Stop* is clicked, it changes the `running` flag in the Worker to false and stops the loop. Also, the *Start* button must be enabled and the *Stop* one disabled. Always when I click in the buttons, the console shows the message which is sent to worker and next the message that is received by the UI Thread from Worker. When I change the `stepTime` `<SELECT>` value, the worker pause time changes. The *Clean* button simply cleans the `<TEXTAREA>`.

What I really got: When I click *Start*, the `<TEXTAREA>` is filled with current time messages and the controls simply don´t respond. Actually all the browser instances (I tested in Firefox) freeze and after some time crash. Apparently, the `setTimeout()` is not working in the Worker, althought it works in UI (for example, in console I type `setTimeout(function() {console.debug("PAUSE!!!")}, id("stepTime").value);`).

A workaround I tried was replace `setTimeout()` calling by `pause()` function. I got this: The page (and the browser) is not freezed. The `<TEXTAREA>` shows the time messages, with the interval initially setted in the `<SELECT>`. The *Clean* button works as expected. However, when the loop starts, it shows the console message in worker (`console.debug("[WORKER] STARTING. running = " + running);`), but not the worker response (`postMessage({msg: "STARTED"});`). Neither the *Start* is disabled not the *stop* is enabled. Besides, if I change the `<SELECT>` value, it does not change the interval. If I really want change the interval, I need reload the page and set another value.

Looking into the code it is obvious why the response is not being called when I start the loop, because the `run()` function is a inifinite loop and therefore response command never is reached.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. How to change the code to make it really assyncronous and
   responsive.
2. Why `setTimeout()` is not working if it should work according the [Web Worker definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage#Importing_scripts_and_libraries).

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: even webworkers are made to run in background without hanging browser, that while(running){} will hang it, the setTimeout will not act as a sleep in php, it is just a function call will not pause the while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) For the first question: 
This code:

```
function run() {
    while(running) {
        postMessage({msg: "TIME", time: new Date().toISOString()});
        // pause();
        setTimeout(function() {console.debug("PAUSE!!!")}, stepTime);
    }
}
```

will hang your browser because it will `postMessage` as fast as your cpu runs because you are inside in a sort of `while(true)` which freezes your webworker. Also the `pause` function will do the same, basically it is a while(true).
To make this code run asynchronous, you should control when `postMessage` is called inside your webworker, for example every 10% of your job completion ...  not inside a while true.

2) For the second question:
this line of code inside the while

```
setTimeout(function() {console.debug("PAUSE!!!")}, stepTime);
```

will not pause it, it does not affect the loop. In javascript there is not a [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) method like the php one.

To have the effect you need replace the run function with this one:

```
function run() {
    if(running){
        postMessage({msg: "TIME", time: new Date().toISOString()});
        setTimeout(function() { run(); }, stepTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

albanx:

Following your suggestion, I changed the `worker.js` code like this:

```
var running = false;
var stepTime = 0;

function run() {
    if(running) {
        postMessage({msg: "TIME", time: new Date().toISOString()});
        setTimeout(run, stepTime); 
    }
}

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    switch(e.data.msg) {
        case "START":
            running = true;
            console.debug("[WORKER] STARTING. running = " + running);
            postMessage({msg: "STARTED"});
            run();
            break;
        case "STOP":
            running = false;
            console.debug("[WORKER] STOPPING. running = " + running);
            postMessage({msg: "STOPPED"});
            break;
        case "STEPTIME":
            stepTime = parseInt(e.data.stepTime);
            console.debug("[WORKER] STEP TIME = " + stepTime);
            postMessage({msg: "STEP TIME CHANGED"});
            break;
        default:
            console.warn("[WORKER] " + e.data);
    }
});
```

This time all worked as expected: the *Stop* button was enabled and really stopped the loop. Also It was possible change the step time changing the `<SELECT>`. Finally, it was possible restart the loop so many times I wanted.

My only question is: Don´t these recrsive calls to `run` (`setTimeout(run, stepTime);`) can create a stack overflow?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: No it does not, because you can stop them with the `running` variable. The `while` was more problematic.

Comment: @albanx : Is there some documentation where I can query about this? i.e. the difference between using `while` and `if`with recursive call?

Comment: I do not think you need any documentation on this. As you can see you can control the recursive call timing with the timeout, on the other hand you can cannot control a while loop. For any javascriot doc I would suggest mozilla site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout